# How to set Tensorflow dynamic_rnn, zero_state without a fixed batch_size?

Tags: python, tensorflow

According to Tensorflow's official website,(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/BasicLSTMCell#zero_state) 
zero_state has to specify a batch_size. 
Many examples I found use this code:

```
    init_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)

    outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, X_in, 
        initial_state=init_state, time_major=False)
```

For training steps, it's okay to fix the batch size. However, when predicting, the test set might not have the same shape as the training set's batch size.
For example, one batch of my training data has shape [100, 255, 128]. The batch size is 100, with 255 steps and 128 inputs. While the test set is [2000, 255, 128]. I can't predict since in dynamic_rnn(initial_state), it already set a fixed batch_size = 100.
How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specify the `batch_size` as a placeholder, not a constant. Just make sure to feed the relevant number in `feed_dict`, which will be different for training and for testing

Importantly, specify `[]` as dimensions for the placeholder, because you might get errors if you specify `None`, as is customary elsewhere. So something like this should work:

```
batch_size = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [], name='batch_size')
init_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, X_in, 
        initial_state=init_state, time_major=False)
# rest of your code
out = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={batch_size:100})
out = sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={batch_size:10})
```

Obviously make sure that the batch parameter matches the shape of your inputs, which `dynamic_rnn` will interpret as `[batch_size, seq_len, features]` or `[seq_len, batch_size, features]` if `time_major` is set to `True`

Comment: it's awesomely helpful!! There are so many basic examples for beginner,yet none of them tell you how to deal with the last non-full-sized batch problem in dynamic_rnn! Thank you @VS_FF

Comment: what if the batch size can only be determined when running? I couldn't know batch size in advance.

Comment: The two constants in the above code were used just as an example. I haven't worked with TF in a while, but I'd imagine you could try to supply a variable instead?

Answer (score 1):

There is a fairly simple implementation. Just remove the initial_state! It is because that the initialization process may pre-allocates a batch-sized memory.

Answer (score 0):

As [@陈狗蛋](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10856002/%E9%99%88%E7%8B%97%E8%9B%8B) answered, there is no need to set `initial_state` in `tf.compat.v1.nn.dynamic_rnn` because it is optional. You can simply do like this

```
outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, 
                                         X_inputs, 
                                         time_major=False, 
                                         dtype=tf.float32)
```

Do not forget to set the `dtype`, here I set `tf.float32`, you can set the `dtype` as you need.

As the [Docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/nn/rnn_cell/LSTMCell#zero_state) of `tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell` says:

> batch_size: int, float, or unit Tensor representing the batch size

The `batch_size` must be an explicit value. So, using a placeholder for the `batch_size` argument is a workaround but not a recommended method. I recommend you do not use it because it may be an invalid way in future versions.